# Does an int field have a default of 0?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a Console app with the following code:

```
    using System;

    namespace HeadfirstPage210bill
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                CableBill myBill = new CableBill(4);
                Console.WriteLine(myBill.iGotChanged);
                Console.WriteLine(myBill.CalculateAmount(7).ToString("£##,#0.00"));
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
                Console.WriteLine(myBill.iGotChanged);
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
```

The class CableBill.cs is the following:

```
    using System;

    namespace HeadfirstPage210bill
    {
        class CableBill
        {
            private int rentalFee;
            public CableBill(int rentalFee) {
                iGotChanged = 0;
                this.rentalFee = rentalFee;
                discount = false;
            }

            public int iGotChanged = 0;


            private int payPerViewDiscount;
            private bool discount;
            public bool Discount {
                set {
                    discount = value;
                    if (discount) {
                        payPerViewDiscount = 2;
                        iGotChanged = 1;
                    } else {
                        payPerViewDiscount = 0;
                        iGotChanged = 2;
                    }
                }
            }

            public int CalculateAmount(int payPerViewMoviesOrdered) {
                return (rentalFee - payPerViewDiscount) * payPerViewMoviesOrdered;
            }

        }
    }
```

The console is returning the following:

[image]

What I can not see is when `payPerViewDiscount` is set to 0. Surely this can only happen when the Discount property is set but if the property Discount is called then the variable `iGotChanged` should be returning 1 or 2, but it seems to stay on 0. Because it is type `int` is there a default value for `payPerViewDiscount` of 0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes the default value of int is `0` you can check using the [`default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword

```
int t = default(int);
```

`t` will hold `0`

Comment: +1 thanks - I thought this might be the case, but it just seems a bit against the strong-type-safe basis of the language

Comment: type-safe strictness ? how come ?

Comment: I'm not really phrasing it correctly ...it seems like a very strict langauge but this default seems contrary to that strictness? ...am I making any sense

Comment: well the default is assigning the same type of default value, so I think its fine, Usually you can't use it before assigning it to some value, since its a field in the class, it will assigned `default` value

Answer (score 4):

Fields in a class are initialized to their default value before the constructor runs. The default value for an int is 0.

Please note that this does *not* apply for local variables, e.g. in methods. They won't be initialized automatically.

```
public class X
{
    private int _field;

    public void PrintField()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_field); // prints 0
    }

    public void PrintLocal()
    {
        int local;
        Console.WriteLine(local); 
        // yields compiler error "Use of unassigned local variable 'local'"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the extra note re local variables - suspect I might have ended up scratching my head about that in the future

Answer (score 2):

Exactly. `int` default value is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, zero is the default value for int.